# can this matrix be positive semidefinite?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

Let $ S \in \mathbb{R}^n $ and $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ Is it possible to find $ \alpha \in \mathbb{R} $, as a function of $A$, such that 
$$ S S^T ( \alpha 1_{n \times n} + A ) + ( \alpha 1_{n\times n} + A^T) S S^T \succeq 0 $$ ?

Comment: For a particular $A$? For all $A$? As a function of $A$?

Comment: as a function of $A$

Comment: It could not for all $A$, expand the left side and take $A=-a.1_{n\times n}$ for some big positive $a$.
As a function of $A$ is a tricky but the answer is still no we have to find a counter-example

Comment: @ToniMhax but then you can just take $\alpha > a$ right ?

Comment: It happens only if $S$ is an eigenvector of $A^T$

Comment: The answer still no

Comment: P Quinton your answer was usefull thou. If posible please restore it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample: take $n=2$, $S = e_1$ and 
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
you get
$$
S S^T ( \alpha 1_{n \times n} + A ) + ( \alpha 1_{n\times n} + A^T) S S^T  
=
A = \begin{pmatrix}
2\alpha & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
that has $-1$ as determinant, so exactly one eigenvalue is negative.

---

If you want to probe deeper, try to prove that there exists such an $\alpha$ if and only if $S$ is an eigenvector of $A^T$